# Get the Product Variation related to default attribute values in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, product-variations

I would like to display the default product attributes form value and it's regular price in my front end template file.

The `var_dump` below shows options in an array. **I Need to get the `[default_attributes]` values.**

```
<?php 
    global $product;
    echo var_dump( $product );
// Need to get the [default_attributes] values
?>
```

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To get the default attributes for a variable product you can use **`WC_Product`** method [**`get_default_attributes()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_default_attributes) this way:

```
<?php 
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type('variable') ){
        $default_attributes = $product->get_default_attributes();

        // Testing raw output
        var_dump($default_attributes);
    }
?>
```

Now to find out which is the corresponding product variation for this "defaults" attributes, is a little more complicated:

```
<?php 
    global $product;

    if( $product->is_type('variable') ){
        $default_attributes = $product->get_default_attributes();
        foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $variation_values ){
            foreach($variation_values['attributes'] as $key => $attribute_value ){
                $attribute_name = str_replace( 'attribute_', '', $key );
                $default_value = $product->get_variation_default_attribute($attribute_name);
                if( $default_value == $attribute_value ){
                    $is_default_variation = true;
                } else {
                    $is_default_variation = false;
                    break; // Stop this loop to start next main lopp
                }
            }
            if( $is_default_variation ){
                $variation_id = $variation_values['variation_id'];
                break; // Stop the main loop
            }
        }

        // Now we get the default variation data
        if( $is_default_variation ){
            // Raw output of available "default" variation details data
            echo '<pre>'; print_r($variation_values); echo '</pre>';

            // Get the "default" WC_Product_Variation object to use available methods
            $default_variation = wc_get_product($variation_id);

            // Get The active price
            $price = $default_variation->get_price(); 
        }
    }
?>
```

This is tested and works.

Comment: Thanks Loic, Is it possible to get the array of the variables if say I have large & green, large & blue, small & green (default value), small & blue. Can I get the variables using default green namely array( L + Green and S + green) returned with their prices?

Comment: @omukiguy The defaults attributes values are only one by attribute and are related to a unique variation… So I don't really catch what do you want now, as it's not what you asked in your question. My answer is answering your question: which is to retrieve the variation related to the default attribute values set in the variable product to get the related variation data as price… Now you can ask a new question if you like. Thanks :)

Comment: Agreed. I wanted to push using one of the default values variables to make a query so i can get all the variations related to the product with that particular default value. This would be echoed with variations price. I do not know if I an clear. something like this. Get all variations with attribute_pa_sizes similar to the default value

`echo $variation_values['attributes']['attribute_pa_sizes'] . ': ' . $price ;`

Comment: What's the `$default_attributes = $product->get_default_attributes();` line for? You never use the `$default_attributes` variable.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Just for christmas decoration… It is just there to know that is related and can be used if needed.

Answer (score 1):

`WC_Product_Data_Store_Interface` offers a way to get a product variation matching a list of attributes for a variable WC_Product with [->find_matching_product_variation()](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-data-stores-class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.html#source-view.1093) :

```
function get_product_default_variation( $WC_Product ) {
  $default_attributes = $WC_Product->get_default_attributes();

  // ->find_matching_product_variation() needs term slugs of matching
  // attributes array to be prefixed with 'attribute_'
  $prefixed_slugs = array_map( function( $pa_name ) {
    return 'attribute_'. $pa_name;
  }, array_keys( $default_attributes ) );

  $default_attributes = array_combine( $prefixed_slugs, $default_attributes );

  $default_variation_id = ( new \WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT() )->find_matching_product_variation( $WC_Product, $default_attributes );

  return wc_get_product( $default_variation_id );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while looking for a simpler way to do it than I was, perhaps a built in WooCommerce function, but for now we still need to find it ourselves.

I did this a little bit differently, and by using microtime to test its performance on my hardware, it runs in about 1/2000 of the time. Here is my code:

```
function setDefaultVariation(): array {
    global $product;
    $all_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
    $default_attributes = $product->get_default_attributes();
    if (empty($default_attributes))
        return $all_variations[0];

    $default_variation_key = -1;
    foreach ($all_variations as $variation) {
        $default_variation_key++;
        //Check if variation has more or less assigned attributes than the default.
        if (getAssignedAttributeCount($variation['attributes']) !== count($default_attributes))
            continue;

        $is_default = 0; //This will count how many attributes match the default values
        //We check each default attribute term and value to see if it matches the term-value pairs of the current variation. Some might have multiple pairs, so we use a counter to know if all are matched
        foreach ($default_attributes as $default_term => $default_value) {
            if($variation['attributes']['attribute_' . $default_term] !== $default_value) {
                break; //A attribute value does not match so this one cant be default, break.
            }else{
                $is_default++;
                if ($is_default === count($default_attributes) ) { //All default attributes matches this variation
                    return $all_variations[$default_variation_key];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $all_variations[0];//If this statement is reached, no default variation was found, so return key of first variation
}

function getAssignedAttributeCount($attributes): int {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if ($attribute !== '')
            $count++;
    }
    return $count;
}
```

The code finds the default attributes for a product, then loops through each variation to check if the variation's attributes matches the default attributes.

It supports products that have multiple attributes, and also checks that the variation has the exact attributes by comparing the number of attributes, so for example (NULL is a where a default value for an attribute is not set):

```
Default
|0|NULL|
Variation 1:
|0|2| -> The 0 matches, but the 2 does not, so this is not default!
Variation 2:
|0|NULL| -> This is the default
```

To achieve this, I added the `getAssignedAttributeCount()` function.

Also note that if no default variation is set, or no variation matching the default values is found, then the first variation is returned.